# Instantiating a new instance of the RobotFixture to pass into a constructor

Tags: java, swing, fest

I'm trying to create a new JPopupMenuFixture by passing a JPopupMenu (testJPopupMenu)  to it as below:
JPopupMenuFixture jpopupMenuFixture = new JPopupMenuFixture(new RobotFixture, testJPopupMenu);

though i'm unsure how to instantiate a new instance of the RobotFixture to pass into the constructor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to instantiate a new instance of the RobotFixture to pass into the constructor?

[RobotFixture.robotWithCurrentAwtHierarchy()](http://fest.googlecode.com/svn-history/r449/trunk/fest/fest-swing/javadocs/org/fest/swing/RobotFixture.html#robotWithCurrentAwtHierarchy%28%29)

or

[RobotFixture.robotWithNewAwtHierarchy()](http://fest.googlecode.com/svn-history/r449/trunk/fest/fest-swing/javadocs/org/fest/swing/RobotFixture.html#robotWithNewAwtHierarchy%28%29)

For more info have a look at [source code of RobotFixture](http://code.google.com/p/fest/source/browse/trunk/fest/fest-swing/src/main/java/org/fest/swing/RobotFixture.java?r=149)